# How to trace a point in jsxgraph when renderer = canvas

Tags: html, canvas, jsxgraph

I am trying to donwload a video from a canvas containing a jsxgraph sketch.
I need to set

JXG.Options.board.renderer = 'canvas';

I discovered that when the renderer is canvas, the trace of a point is not drawn, for some reason.

Is there a way to draw the trace of a point with renderer = canvas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time being, traces of elements are not supported by JSXGraph. A possible workaround might be to use the default SVG renderer and dump - when needed - the SVG image into a canvas element, using `board.renderer.dumpToCanvas()`, see https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/JXG.SVGRenderer.html#dumpToCanvas.